# Instruments (allocation) and find which objects creates problems

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, instruments, memory-leaks

I have memory issues (I'm using ARC) and i'm sure that I create `strong` `@property` somewhere where it should be `weak`. I run instruments and it show me this allocations:
[image]

It's clearly an not-releasing problem. But can i find it in Instruments?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Blue one is mine after tap a lot to change screens.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switching to the call tree view in the Allocations instrument can help you find where the allocations are occurring in your code. Use the jump bar to switch to the call tree view.

When you switch to the call tree view, you should see a series of checkboxes to the left of the call tree. Selecting the Invert Call Tree and Hide System Libraries checkboxes allow you to find your code in the call tree.

You can also use the Inspection Range buttons and the graph's timeline to focus on the times when memory usage increases. Click on the timeline, click the left inspection range button, click the timeline a second time, and click the right inspection range button to set an inspection range.

Comment: Thank you. Now i see everything. Strange is that it is only works in simulator but thats ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

> I have memory issues (I'm using ARC) and i'm sure that I create strong @property somewhere where it should be weak.

Instruments can detect some of these automatically:

- Click the "Leaks" Track on the left
- Click the display popup and choose "Cycles and Roots" (this is the button labeled "Statistics" in your screenshot)

---

After that list is emptied (and any/all leaks are removed), then attack it using [Heapshot Analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/). This allows you to focus on un-released growths over a range of time.

Comment: I don't have leaks (like for strong properties in view elements) I just store to much values - probably iOS thinks this is desirable action. I add two more screens to my question.

Comment: @SimpleMan a strong/circular reference is classified as a leak, even though traditional memory scan by leaks does not report it. that's why reference cycle detection is placed in leaks. i've added a link which introduces you to Heapshot Analysis.